# What might be possible reasons that I get "Cannot Allocate Memory" error on forking()?

Tags: c, shell, unix, fork

I am creating a simple Unix shell in C. I use the fork() to clone the process and exec to execute a new one. It works fine when you are inputting data for the first time in the shell. But when it comes the second iteration fork returns -1.

e.g

...>ls -l /

/*results here*/

...>ls -l /

forking failed

here is a part of the code:

```
int execute(char path[80],char *args[]){
pid_t pid;
if((pid=fork())<0){
 printf("forking failed"); // The forking failed due to Cannot allocate memory error
 exit(0);
}else if(pid==0){
 execv(path,args);
}else{
 wait(NULL);
}
return 0
}
```

where path is "bin/ls" and args "ls",NULL

the main is looks like

```
int main(){
 while(1){
 //read from keyboard
 //find the program path
 //fill args
 execute(path,args);
 }
}
```

Comment: Consult errno and the fork(2) manpage.  This doesn’t belong here.

Comment: The `ls` command is usually something built in, but your question implies its a c program you wrote that caused the problem.  Clarification on this?

Comment: I have already consulted it.@tchrist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your first `if` branch to this:

```
if((pid=fork())<0){
 perror("forking failed");
 exit(0);
}
```

This will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: I did it and the error is : Cannot allocate memory. Any thoughts why this might happened?

Comment: At a guess, I'd say you are running out of memory on your machine.

Comment: It happened for the reason it says it happened for.

Comment: That's a good guess but I don't think it's the case since it always happens on the second attempt to execute a command as shown above.

Comment: @JustCurious Show us more of your `main` function, perhaps?  It seems likely that you're doing something bad in there.

Comment: yeah, but any guess why? @tchrist

Comment: @JustCurious Maybe you aren't freeing memory during your parsing of args and finding your path.

Comment: My guess is that your first execv fails and the child is in the while loop in a fork bomb.  Check whether the first execv succeeds.

Comment: execv succeed since i get the correct results back..isnt this enough to prove that execv works properly?

Comment: @JustCurious You should probably be checking the return value of `execv` just to be sure, but it does sound like its working.  On the other hand, `bin/ls` probably doesn't represent an executable unless your current working directory is `/`.

Comment: i checked exec and no error there. my working dir is home/myName. bin/ls is found using some code i have to find the program from different directories. There should be something with memory that other variables occupy I guess. How is it possible to interfere with fork?? and is there a way to allocate more memory to fork()?